# sql syntax errors in azure database management portal

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, azure

I have an SQL server DB script file that I'm trying to upload to Azure.

When I execute this script in SQL Server Management Studio it runs without any errors. However when I open the file in the azure management portal and execute it I get syntax errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 296
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.

The code in line 296 is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarsForRent]  WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CarsForRent_CarTypes] FOREIGN KEY([CarTypeID])
```

Second error:

> Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 299
>   Constraint 'FK_CarsForRent_CarTypes' does not exist.

The code in line 299 is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarsForRent] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CarsForRent_CarTypes]
```

and the third error:

> Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 299
>   Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.

My only guess is that azure management portal doesn't support all SQL statements.

How can I fix my code so that I could upload my DB to azure?

Thanks!

Comment: Move `WITH CHECK ` to the end of first query.

Comment: When you say the script runs fine from SSMS, do you mean against a Windows Azure SQL database or an on-prem one?  The problem code may be before line 296 so you might include the preceding statement in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a vital piece when you are creating a foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarsForRent]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CarsForRent_CarTypes] FOREIGN KEY([CarTypeID])
REFERENCES TableName(ColumnName)    --<-- the table and column this FK 
                                       -- is referrencing to
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used the "Deploy Database to SQL Azure" tool, from sql server.
Right-click on the DB > Tasks > Deploy Database to SQL Azure.